# I'm stuck in gradle errors for days. I've no idea how to fix this. I can't find the solution anywhere in the internet

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

Whenever I'm trying to sync the files of my app to the gradle files it shows the following error. I can't figure out the solution and I'm stuck here for days.

```
Android resource compilation failed
Output:  C:\Users\KIIT\AndroidStudioProjects\QuestionMe2\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml:2: error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity.

Command: C:\Users\KIIT\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\38553b6ae651a252892876ddc663dbcd\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
        C:\Users\KIIT\AndroidStudioProjects\QuestionMe2\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
        C:\Users\KIIT\AndroidStudioProjects\QuestionMe2\app\src\main\res\layout\activity_main.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #2
```

I've no idea what this says. Please help me.

Comment: Can you post the activity_main.xml file?

Comment: error is on `activity_main.xml` file. please check first line error message, you might wrote text before xml entry tag. or just show `activity_main.xml` file to give solution

Comment: Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 0):

Move this line of code at your activity_main.xml to the first line!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.